# Object error while running arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management() outside of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, pycharm, runtimeerror

I have a script that starts by creating a FileGDB by calling [arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-file-gdb.htm).

It runs without error on my own laptop, but raises an error when my colleagues try to run it outside of ArcGIS Pro.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import arcpy
 arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\LOCAL\\Project"
 home = "C:\\LOCAL\\Project"
 GDB = "test.gdb"
 arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(home, GDB)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 20234, in CreateFileGDB
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 20231, in CreateFileGDB
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CreateFileGDB_management(*gp_fixargs((out_folder_path, out_name, out_version), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 498, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

When run from the Python window inside ArcGIS Pro there's no issue, it only happens when it's run from outside.

I've tried to run it in 2 different ways:

- In PyCharm by setting the interpreter to C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe
- Inserting the code one-by-one directly in C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe

I've tested this on 2 different devices, both giving the same error.

The complete script works on my own laptop but I can't seem to get it to work on other devices. It feels like I'm overlooking a setting somewhere.

Comment: Just thinking out aloud. Have they installed ArcPro not in the default install location?

Comment: They did install it in the default install location. I also compared their installation folders to mine (as mine is working) and I can't seem to find a difference.

I thought maybe it has something to do with them having a previous installation of Python but I can't seem to find anything about that either.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's on another machine, perhaps it is possible that they don't have a C://LOCAL//Project folder.

Try adding this after you define the string value for home:

```
    import os
    if not os.path.exists(home):
        os.makedirs(home)
```

If that doesn't work, try putting r in front of the string quotes:

```
home = r'C:\\LOCAL\\Project'
```

Also, if you've already run it from ArcGIS Pro, it could be failing because the GDB already exists. If so, try calling this at the top of the script to allow overwriting:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

Comment: of course, you'll import os at the top of the script with the arcpy import

Comment: I tried this but none of it helped. It just seems so weird to me that I can't do the most basic Arcpy functions outside of ArcPro.